# Don't capture matched part of string with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to capture part of matched string. Here's what I've done:

```
var myRegex = /(^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.|$)/;
vary myString = "33.11.999";
var match = myRegex.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

console will output 33.11. but i want to exclude the last dot. Is it possible to do that using regex?

Comment: Why do you need to match the end of string? What was your intention? Please add your pattern requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `positive lookahead (?=)`, to ignore the last dot.

```js
var myRegex = /(^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}(?=\.)|$)/;
var myString = "33.11.999";
var match = myRegex.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

So why not capture only the part you want ?

```
var myRegex = /(^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2})\.|$/;
var myString = "33.11.999";
var match = myRegex.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var regex=/\d+\.\d+(?=\.\d+)/;
var str='33.11.999';
var result=str.match(regex);
console.info(result[0]);
```

you can write like this too.